# xStream crashes when there are more fields in the XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, xstream

xStream

When I have the following XML code:

```
<xml>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <url>http://www.google.nl</url>
</xml>
```

And I read this with my Java code everything works fine, but when the XML changes, for example to:

```
<xml>
  <test>test</test>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <url>http://www.google.nl</url>
</xml>
```

I get an error, but I want that the program doesn't stop, and don't use the field test. Is there a way to handle this exception without that the program stops?

```
Exception in thread "main"         com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$UnknownFieldExce    ption: No such field Version.iets
---- Debugging information ----
field               : iets
class               : Version
required-type       : Version
converter-type      :     com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /Version/iets
line number         : 1
version             : null
-------------------------------
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java XStream - Ignore tag that doesn't exist in XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409717/java-xstream-ignore-tag-that-doesnt-exist-in-xml)

Answer (score 5):

XStream 1.4.5 makes you simple to deal with unknown tags. Use ignoreUnknownElements for tags which are not implemented yet or has been removed and you are dealing with old xml.

> http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream.html#ignoreUnknownElements%28%29

You can also specify which particular tag you would like to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Brian Agnew I found the answer, this is the solution:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver()) {
            protected MapperWrapper wrapMapper(MapperWrapper next) {
                return new MapperWrapper(next) {
                    public boolean shouldSerializeMember(Class definedIn, String fieldName) {
                        try {
                            return definedIn != Object.class || realClass(fieldName) != null;
                        } catch(CannotResolveClassException cnrce) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        };
```